# Updating progress in SharePoint Job

Tags: sharepoint

I have a **long-running SharePoint timer job** and I would like to display it's **progress** in central administration (so I'm using `SPJobDefinition.UpdateProgress(int percentage)` method).

Let's say I have 50 000 elements on a list that i want to update in a foreach loop. If I place something like `job.UpdateProgress((int) itemNo / itemCount)` in a loop, would it send a web request to SharePoint server each time method is called (50 000 times), or only if the percentage actually changed (no more than 100 times)?

I don't want any noticeable performance degradation because of this and I suppose that more requests might slow down the job.

Also, what tool is good to see the requests and responses (Fiddler? Or something else would be better for Sharepoint?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(in SP2010) Every time you call job.UpdateProgress, the SPJobDefinition class will send an SPRequest.  SPJobDefinition does not internally track its' percent complete, so it has no way of knowing whether your new int is an update or not unless it contacts the server, so it just contacts the server.  So yes, calling this 50000 times may slow down your code significantly.

The easiest way to figure out stuff like this (since the online MSDN documentation can be very sparse at times) is to use a .Net reflector on the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll.  Personally, I tend to use ilSpy.